# Reference error "Warning--empty year in (...); set to "????""

Tags: bibtex, errors, texstudio, zotero

I am new to latex/bibtex, and I can't figure out where this error is coming from.
I generated a .bib file from a Zotero collection, and try to generate a bibliography in my latex document.
However, the references generated in the document fail to get the year of publication correctly, all though it is present in the .bib file.

The reduced .bib file looks like this:

```
@article{packham_interactive_2005,
  title = {Interactive Visualisation for Decision Support and Evaluation of Robustness—in Theory and in Practice},
  volume = {19},
  issn = {1474-0346},
  url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1474034605000613},
  doi = {10.1016/j.aei.2005.07.006},
  timestamp = {2016-04-06T06:59:27Z},
  number = {4},
  journaltitle = {Advanced Engineering Informatics},
  shortjournal = {Advanced Engineering Informatics},
  series = {Computing in Civil Engineering11th International Workshop of the European Group for Intelligent Computing in Engineering},
  author = {Packham, I. S. J. and Rafiq, M. Y. and Borthwick, M. F. and Denham, S. L.},
  urldate = {2016-04-06},
  date = {2005-10},
  pages = {263--280},
  note = {00019},
  keywords = {decision support,Genetic algorithms,Interactive visualisation,Knowledge discovery,Robustness evaluation},
}
```

And I am generating the bibliography like in the following MWE(I tried 2 different styles, one from the elsevier template, and one available here (http://www.frontiersin.org/Design/bst/frontiersinSCNS_ENG_HUMS.bst) which both fail to load years):

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}

fermentum \cite{packham_interactive_2005}

\section{References}
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliographystyle{frontiersinSCNS_ENG_HUMS}
\bibliography{Interactive_Optimization}


\end{document}
```

> [2] I. S. J. Packham, M. Y. Raq, M. F. Borthwick, S. L. Denham,
>   Interactive visualisation for decision support and evaluation of
>   robustness|in theory and in practice 19 (????) 263{280. 00019.

A first compilation highlighted the following error: 
Warning--empty year in (...); set to ????
And now, no more errors are displayed, although the years are still represented by (????) instead of "2005".

Am I missing something? Is this a problem with the bib style I am using? Or with the bib file I generated from Zotero? Any clues on how to fix it? Note that I also tried changing the label in the bib file from "date" to "year", without solving the issue. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)? Can you reproduce the problem with a commonly available bib style? Otherwise can you please point us to where we can get these styles from?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added a MWE which produces the same error. Sorry, got a bit lost creating the MWEB though, hope the separate bib example will be enough. I added a link to the style I used, as not sure where to find other "common" styles. Thanks if you have any further tips!

Comment: @samcarter, sorry, couldn't edit my previous comment to include your name :')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the Zotero complement to [Ross's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344437/31980) (which is imo correct on the bibtex, though I'm pretty sure underscores in citekeys are fine), note that Zotero can export both BibLaTeX and BibTeX. This is also true for the Bettter BibTeX add-on which you may be using (and if not should consider). Your MWE is from a BibLaTeX export.
Zotero's BibTeX export will do exactly the things that Ross fixed for you in the MWE automatically: correctly separate out the date into year and month fields. (It will also do a couple of other things differently that align more closely with standard bibtex).

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I wasn't aware of this difference between the Better BibTex and BibLaTeX exports. With bibtex, my problem was solved. I confirm also that the underscores work fine.

Comment: So if i understood you correctly: I have to use BBT in order to fix the "broken" Zotero BibTeX export, because it uses date and not year? Is there a way to use this for the automatic sync between Zotero and Overleaf?

Comment: No, nothing in Zotero is broken in this respect. Zotero's bibtex export separates the date out into separate year, month, and day fields and Zotero's biblatex export has a single data field in YYYY-MM-DD format as per the specifications. The MWE is biblatex export from Zotero. Overleaf is able to pull in either of the two depending on your settings.

Answer (score 2):

I wish to point out that you are using Elsevier's class file, `elsarticle.cls`, with a `bst` file prepared for a Springer journal. It is hard to imagine that is your deliberate intention. If you are preparing a paper for one of those publishers, you need to review their instructions.

Nevertheless, the critical thing that makes your MWE work is to recognize that the `frontiersinSCNS_ENG_HUMS` file is an `authoryear` style. This means you need to tell the elsarticle class that you are using `authoryear`. This is done by adding that option to the the class options. To solve the empty year warning, just add `year = {2005}` to the bibitem.

I also removed dashes and underscores from file names and bibitem keys. These are fine in `BibLaTeX`, but I think they create problems here. There may be another error in the bibitem somewhere. I finished up pasting in into JabRef,  running `Cleanup Entry` and pasting it back into the MWE.

The MWE and result are as follows:

```
\documentclass[preprint,authoryear]{elsarticle} 

\begin{filecontents*}{InteractiveOptimization.bib}
@Article{packham05,
    author       = {Packham, I. S. J. and Rafiq, M. Y. and Borthwick, M. F. and Denham, S. L.},
    title        = {Interactive Visualisation for Decision Support and Evaluation of Robustness---in Theory and in Practice},
    year         = {2005},
    volume       = {19},
    number       = {4},
    pages        = {263--280},
    note         = {00019},
    date         = {2005-10},
    doi          = {10.1016/j.aei.2005.07.006},
    issn         = {1474-0346},
    journal      = {Advanced Engineering Informatics},
    keywords     = {decision support,Genetic algorithms,Interactive visualisation,Knowledge discovery,Robustness evaluation},
    series       = {Computing in Civil Engineering11th International Workshop of the European Group for Intelligent Computing in Engineering},
    shortjournal = {Advanced Engineering Informatics},
    timestamp    = {2016-04-06T06:59:27Z},
    url          = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1474034605000613},
    urldate      = {2016-04-06},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

fermentum \citep{packham05}

%\section{References}
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliographystyle{frontiersinSCNS_ENG_HUMS}
\bibliography{InteractiveOptimization}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! Your answer was very helpful to understand a bit better what is going on. @adam.smith 's answer below complemented well, indicating that a Better BibTex export of the bib file has the correct format, as you manually fixed in my MWE. I think the error was coming from the Better BibLatex export.

Comment: However, though interesting to note that authoryear should be indicated as a class option, I found that the style I am using can in fact also work without that option (just plain numbered e.g. [1]), so I don't think that was the main issue here. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

So if you are like me and made quite a bunch of wrong references and don't want to fix it manually, you can use the regex:

```
(journaltitle = {([^}]+)})
```

and replace with:

```
journaltitle = {$2},\n\tjournal = {$2}
```

to fix the journal name. And for the year:

```
(\s(date = {([^-}]+)-[^}]+}))
```

and replace with:

```
$1,\n\tyear = {$3}
```

With that said, I am not great with regex, so you should probably check out each match by hand to see if it is doing what you want it to be doing. Also, if you have some items that are already correct, this will add duplicate journal and year fields.

EDIT: I don't do this any more. I've solved this problem by using [betterbibtex](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex).

Comment: the expressions are not completely generic. for instance, for a date that has only year, it just doesn't find anything. And if the journal name has a {IEEE} or {ACM} in its name it also messes it up.